# how to output descending number in html textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

HTML code

```
  <form id = "numbersdescendingodd">
       Resultdescendingodd : <input type = "text" name = "resultdescendingodd" id = "dodd" max = "20"><br>
       <input type = "button" onclick = "descendingodd()" value = "Clickhere">
       <br>
  </form>
```

Javascript code

```
function descendingodd(){
    var x = 0
    for(var i = 21 ; i>=1; i-=2){
        var result = document.getElementById('dodd');
        result.value = (`${i}`)
     }
 }
```

i want my output textbox are : 21,19,17,15,etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the textbox's value to each descending odd number one at a time and so once your code finishes running it will be left set to the last number (1).

Try changing `result.value = (`${i}`)` to `result.value += i + ','`. It won't do exactly what you want (it'll have a comma after the last number) but I'm guessing you'll be able to figure it out from there.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your descendingodd function with this

```
function descendingodd(){
 var x = "";
 var result = document.getElementById('dodd');
 for(var i = 21 ; i>=1; i-=2){
     x += i;
     x += ","; 
 }
 result.value = x;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function descendingodd() {
  const text = document.getElementById('dodd').value;
  const numbers = text.split(',').map(Number);
  const r = numbers.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});  
  document.getElementById('dodd').value = r.join();  
}
```

```html
<form id = "numbersdescendingodd">Resultdescendingodd : 
   <input type = "text" name = "resultdescendingodd" id = "dodd" max = "20" value="5,17,21,19"><br>
  <input type = "button" onclick = "descendingodd()" value = "Clickhere">
<br>
</form>
```